# Overriding sub-functions in python class inheritance

Tags: python, class, inheritance, super, superclass

I have trouble with understanding what happens when overriding a function that is used within another function in python class inheritance. Now say I have two classes `A` and `B`, with `B` as subclass, with the folliwing definitions:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1
    def print(self):
        self._print()
    def _print(self):
        print(self.var)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1
    def _print(self):
        print(self.var * 2)
```

now say:

```py
aa = A()
bb = B()
```

Now, in the above code, `_print()` is overridden in B. As I expect, calling `bb.print()` prints 2, as does calling `bb.print`(). However, executing `super(B, bb).print()` also prints 2, and only executing `super(B, bb)._print()` prints 1. This is what I do not fully understand. I expected to have `super(B, bb).print()` printing 1 as I call a method of the superclass.

Could someone elaborate on this behaviour?

Comment: `super()` just tells Python to look further up the inheritance chain to find a particular method.  The `self` passed to that method is still `bb`, an instance of `B`, so any further methods that it calls will be looked for in `B` first.

Comment: "as I call a method of the superclass." yes, you did call a method defined on the superclass. But Python always dynamically resolves attributes, so even inside that method `bb._print` is still called, and that resolves to `B._print`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it makes sense that way. I think I expected that somehow `super(B, bb)` returns an instance of `A` rather then enabeling solely calling a function of `A` while self remaind `bb`. 'This is what I understood from the documentation of `super()`: ”Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type”, which feels like the entire parent is used in the method call

Comment: Note that if you want methods resolved wrt the currently *defined* class, that's what name mangling/ double underscores are for. Use ``def __print`` and ``self.__print()`` (note the two leading underscores) and it should work as initially expected.