# why is there difference between calling super().foo and super().__getattribute__("foo")

Tags: python, python-3.x, super

I thought super() would always try to run with method(or attribute) in base class until I encountered a use case that gets attribute of child class with `super().__getattribute__("foo")`. Simplified code shows as below.

```
class Base:
    value = "base"

    def foo(self):
        print(f"Base foo, {self.value}")

class Derived(Base):
    value = "derived"

    def foo(self):
        print(f"Derived foo, {self.value}")


    def bar(self):
        print(f"Derived bar {self.value}")
        print(super().value)
        print(super().__getattribute__("value"))
        super().foo()
        super().__getattribute__('foo')()

d = Derived()
d.bar()
```

the output,

```
Derived bar derived
base
derived
Base foo, derived
Derived foo, derived
```

is somewhat beyond my previous understanding, is only `__getattribute__` an exception? I can not get any further detail with this [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super), hope anyone can help me understand this clearer, thanks!

---

Edit to follow `__getattribute__` issue, as below:

```
class Base:
    value = "base"

    def foo(self):
        print(f"Base foo, {self.value}")


    def __getattribute__(self, k):
        print(f"Base get attr {self}, {k}")
        return super().__getattribute__(k)


class Derived(Base):
    value = "derived"

    def foo(self):
        print(f"Derived foo, {self.value}")


    def __getattribute__(self, k):
        print(f"Derived get attr {self}, {k}")
        return super().__getattribute__(k)


    def bar(self):
        print("Derived bar")
        print(super().value)
        print(super().__getattribute__("value"))

d = Derived()
d.bar()
```

and output is:

```
Derived get attr <__main__.Derived object at 0x7fb0621dba90>, bar
Base get attr <__main__.Derived object at 0x7fb0621dba90>, bar
Derived bar
base
Base get attr <__main__.Derived object at 0x7fb0621dba90>, value
derived
```

Comment: It *is* always getting the attribute/method in the base class (rather, *the next* class in the method resolution order). Where do you think `super` is not doing this, exactly?

Comment: Maybe, this will be revealing: `object.__getattribute__(d, 'value')`

Comment: Someone just recently posted a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67377122/overriding-sub-functions-in-python-class-inheritance#comment119092954_67377122

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I long thought that `super()` actually returned an *object* of the base class. I had a long time to understand that it was only a proxy to look **once** for an attribute.

Comment: @SergeBallesta where did you get this `it was only a proxy to look once for an attribute` ? I think what confuses me is then why `super().xxx` does not invoke a call of `object.__getattribute__(d, 'xxx')`

Comment: @kuixiong because `super()` returns a `super` object. this is in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) "Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. This is useful for accessing inherited methods that have been overridden in a class."

Answer (score 2):

The `super()` helper creates a proxy which modifies attribute access *on itself*. As such:

- `super().foo` looks up `foo` on the `super` proxy.
- `super().__getattribute__` looks up `__getattribute__` on the `super` proxy.

Notably, the result of either has no knowledge that it was looked up via `super`: *any further action on the result proceeds as normal*. When the looked up thing is a data descriptor (like a method or property), it is bound to the initial `self`, not `super`.

Ultimately, looking up `super().__getattribute__` will in the usual case merely find, directly or via a wrapper, the standard `object.__getattribute__` and bind it to `self`. As such, calling `super().__getattribute__("foo")` is equivalent to `object.__getattribute__(self, "foo")` – there is no `super` involved in looking up `.foo`.

---

It might help to compare how the expressions `super().foo` and `super().__getattribute__("foo")` can be decomposed:

```py
# super().foo
s = super()
foo = s.foo
# super().__getattribute__("foo")
s = super()
g = s.__getattribute__
foo = g("foo")
```

In the second case, the `super` proxy is not involved in looking up `.foo`.

Comment: thanks, your answer really shed light upon me, I have never realized that `s.__getattribute__` and `s.__getattribute('foo')` are 2 steps in this case (just forgot that `function` is also a callable object, when combined with this `super()` invocation).

Answer (score 1):

To be more specific, `super` essentially skips the current class when looking up some attribute/method. In the case of single inheritance, that is equivalent to looking in the base class. This is *always* happening in the above.

```
In [38]: class Base:
    ...:     value = "base"
    ...:
    ...:     def foo(self):
    ...:         print(f"Base foo, {self.value}")
    ...:
    ...: class Derived(Base):
    ...:     value = "derived"
    ...:
    ...:     def foo(self):
    ...:         print(f"Derived foo, {self.value}")
    ...:
    ...:
    ...:     def bar(self):
    ...:         print(f"Derived bar {self.value}")
    ...:         print(super().value)
    ...:         print(super().__getattribute__("value"))
    ...:         super().foo()
    ...:         super().__getattribute__('foo')()
    ...:
    ...: d = Derived()

In [39]: Derived.mro()
Out[39]: [__main__.Derived, __main__.Base, object]
```

I suspect what is confusing you is:

```
super().__getattribute__("value")
```

Well, in this case, `super()` skipps `__main__.Derived`, looks in `__main__.Base`, doesn't find anything, then finally, finds `__getattribute__` in `object`. It doesn't then magically make every other attribute access skip `Derived`. Indeed, `object.__getattribute__` is what would happen *anyway*, Note:

```
In [40]: object.__getattribute__(d, 'value')
Out[40]: 'derived'
```

So, this works no differently when you pass `"foo"` to `object.__getattribute__`,

```
In [41]: object.__getattribute__(d, 'foo')
Out[41]: <bound method Derived.foo of <__main__.Derived object at 0x7f927ba46460>>
```

Now, when you call `super().foo`, it *skips* `__main__.Derived`, looks in `__main__.Base` and finds a `foo`, so that is essentially:

```
In [42]: Base.foo(d)
Base foo, derived
```

Comment: thanks, I am still a little confused by `super().__getattribute__("value")`, when you said `doesn't find anything, then finally, finds __getattribute__ in object`, isn't there a `value` attribute in `Base`, why is it not found? And I tried another way in funciont `bar`, when I use `super().bar` it will fail with `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'bar'`,  why wouldn't it fall back to `object.__getattribute__(d, 'bar')`?

Comment: @kuixiong `value` is irrelevant, `super()` is resolving `__getattribute__`, not `value`.  `super().__getattribute__ is object.__attribute__`.

Comment: thanks, I think now I get the superficial reason, `super().__getattribute__` just equals `object.__getattribute__` unless I implement explicitly it in `Base`. But do you know why `super().value` does not invoke `__getattribute__` like `d.value` does?

Comment: @kuixiong it does invokes `__getattribute__` of *`super`* because `super().value` is calling `.value` on a `super` object.

Comment: why? I thought `__getattribute__` would be invoked every time you access attribute of an instance as described [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__)

Comment: @kuixiong again, because `super().value` is accessing `super.__getattribute__`

Comment: sorry for being noob, but I tried to implement a `__getattribute__` in `Base`, and it shows `super().value` does not invoke it, I've updated it in my question, could you take a look?

Comment: @kuixiong: `super().value` is an attribute access on an instance of `super`. Accessing an attribute on an instance of `super` uses `super`'s `__getattribute__`. Where in this process would you expect `Base.__getattribute__` to become involved?

Comment: oh, I think I get the difference now, `super()` is just another instance, I was used to take it as `Base` and forgot about the difference between `super()` and `Base`.